# Software to detect mp3 almost-duplicates?

Tags: mp3, music, tags, id3, deduplication

Because of some unfortunate circumstances I noticed I irrevertibly mixed up my sorted and retagged mp3s with an old backup. That means now I have files that are basically duplicates except for the id3 tags and paths. [FSlint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/) does a nice job of finding real duplicates, but is there any free tool to detect duplicate mp3s that differ in their ID3s? My preference is a linux tool, but windows would be acceptable, too.

Comment: I guess you know about [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard), which can take acoustic fingerprints and uses them to find out the appropriate tags? Maybe you can retag the MP3s and then sort out the duplicates.

Comment: @slhck thanks for mentioning it, yes picard is what I'll be using (again) if no automated solution shows up

Comment: You can try using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/duplicates.aspx) Windows tool from codeproject which is available both as source code and executable. [Here's](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Wait-isnt-that-MP3-THAT-MP3-Fingerprinting-your-musicaudio) a blog post about how it works internally. Since I haven't used it myself and don't know how it handles extremely large collections, posting only a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EasyTAG](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/) can do this all and more easily. Most importantly for your purposes, it allows you to define and use a naming scheme based on the ID3 tags.

Edit: After rereading the question, this isn't *exactly* what you wanted. However, after renaming the files, you can use FSlint to delete the duplicates.

Comment: easytag is a good tool, I'm basically doing what you suggest with picard now - first retagging (again...) and then fslint.

Comment: in addition to easyTAG and picard I'm now also using [DupeGuru](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_me/) for some good (almost)dupe search

Answer (score 5):

[DupeGuru](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_me/) does a nice job comparing tags or also only the audio content.

[image: DupeGuru]

[DuMP3](http://dump3.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) claims even more features but I didn't spend enough effort to get it running (32 bit SWT on 64 bit linux...)

[DupeMusicMatch](http://dupemusicmatch.sourceforge.net/?p=example#diffoptions) might also help, but I didn't try that yet.